# sending an email via multiple mail servers?

Tags: networking, smtp

We know that SMTP is used to send email as picture below shows:
[image]

So it seems that two mail servers are involved.

But I had a look at header of an e-mail message, there are fours `Received:` header lines, which indicates the mail message passed through 5 different SMTP servers before being delivered to the receiver’s mail box.

So why five mail servers are involved? doesn't two mail servers suffice?

Comment: Mail redirection or forwarding? It depends on how each of the mail servers is configured. Some users have a local and a remote mail server.

Comment: *"Doesn't two mail servers suffice?"* - Not always. I have a local mail server I regularly use, but my ISP requires outgoing mail to be transmitted through their own system to prevent spam. So that local mail server forwards messages it receives to the ISP mail system, which then passes that email traffic on to its final destination. And roughly the same process happens in reverse. My incoming mail is delivered to a third-party service for security/spam reasons, then is transmitted to my local mail server. So in either direction, a minimum of three devices are involved.

Answer (score 2):

SMTP was originally designed with the ability to relay messages. Two servers is just the ideal, most common case.

(It goes back to the days when a single unified Internet didn't quite exist yet, and sometimes mail had go [through multiple worlds](http://dotat.at/tmp/JANET-Mail-Gateways.pdf). For example, when MILNET first split off from ARPANET, the original plans were that they would be connected *only* via SMTP mailbridges.)

So there's a couple of possibilities, ordered from the sender to the recipient:

**Non-SMTP transports**

Not all "Received:" headers mean that SMTP was used. Some web mail apps (e.g. Roundcube) add their own Received header describing how the message was submitted via HTTP from the user's browser.

(It could even be that someone's sending you a message from the past through UUCP!)

**Local MTA (smarthost)**

Sometimes – mainly on servers running Linux or BSD – mail is first submitted to the computer's internal MTA (mail server) running on `localhost`, which is then configured to forward everything to the network's central mail server. Such a configuration is often called "smarthost" mode.

An advantage of this method is that you don't need to configure SMTP server parameters in every program – they can instead just ask "the OS" to deliver a message.

**Branch office servers**

Similarly, it's possible that outgoing mail would first go through a "local" SMTP server that's physically in the same network, and from there to a "central" corporate server (which might be handling DKIM etc.) that's physically in another state or even in another country, and only then to the Internet.

(I'm not sure if this *happens* these days when 24/7 Internet access is readily available to business customers, but it's still technically very possible.)

**Mail proxies and firewalls**

It could be that the recipient, or perhaps even the sender, has a two-layer mail system: one group of servers can receive connections from the Internet but cannot access the actual mail storage; the other group has access to the mail storage but no Internet access.

This is a common security measure – even if someone manages to break into the outer servers, they will not be able to leak anyone's stored mail.

**Other SMTP-based filters**

Some mail filters (anti-spam, anti-malware, etc.) work like SMTP relays. That is, as soon as the mail server receives your message, it forwards the message over SMTP to e.g. Amavisd on `localhost:10031`, which then scans it and forwards it *back* to the same mail server on yet another SMTP port. That's 3 "Received" headers for a single machine.

**Delivery to mail storage**

Often mail storage is handled by a different service than SMTP; it could even be on a different machine entirely. When the recipient's SMTP service receives a message, it might use the LMTP protocol to pass it over to the IMAP service. This might add yet another Received: header. (LMTP is a variation of SMTP with slight adjustments to make it more suitable for local delivery.)

Answer (score -2):

E-mails are tied with the TCP/IP protocol, which is the heart of internet. And the process of going of E-mails from server to server is E-mail routing. Let's see how it works.

First, suppose your E-mail address is xxx@example.com and your friend's is yyy@example.com. You send an E-mail to him. First your E-mail goes to your E-mail provider's MTA through SMTP. SMTP does not understand the domain name. So SMTP needs to consult the DNS server for the IP address. Now once it has got the IP address, now SMTP will check if the Domain has any **M**ail e**X**change (**MX**) servers. MX servers provide additional information on routing. There are MX records on the domain which contains the necessary information on Mail servers.  Now SMTP will route the E-mail through the MTA servers. Now once the recepient MTA is reached, MTA will decide where the E-mail needs to be put, and check if the Client is using POP, POP3 or IMAP. Then your friend gets the E-mail.

The MX records are configured by the server administrators, which helps SMTP route E-mails in correct way.

Hope that Helps